# how to get maven surefire to produce incremental console output?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

My maven surefire tests don't produce any console output while running the actual tests themselves, i.e. the console shows the output below, and then spins for the duration of the test.  When the test is completed, the console output is available, but not until then.  So the question is, how can I disable this buffering?

```
[INFO] Using configured provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Concurrency config is parallel='none', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=2, useUnlimitedThreads=false
```

Here's the relevant section of my pom:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- version 2.12 has a bug in single-test -->
            <version>2.11</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.11</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

It's running on (ahem) Windows, if that matters.

Comment: Just via a patch to the plugin ? I'm not sure if it's caused by the plugin...but it can...cause there seemed to be running multiple threads which must be synchronized with the output ...

Comment: Don't you see anything else? You should see, at least, the number of executed tests

Comment: @CarlosTasada after the test completes, the full console output is available, but until completion, there's nothing further.

Comment: How you _write_ to the console? Using log4j, logback, System.out, etc?

Comment: Both system.out and apache commons log.

Comment: @joeltruher One thing I'd remove from this question is the references to Jenkins.  Jenkins has nothing to do with this problem.  This is a Maven Surefire issue.  I get the same problem running my TestNG tests from Team City.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203756/maven-displaying-unit-test-currently-running.

Comment: @JohnChesshir done