# maven surefire: how to print current test being run?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Is there any way to get maven surefire to print the name of every unit test (i.e., test method) it's starting?

Something like:

```
testFoo: ... passed
testBar: ... failed
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203756/maven-displaying-unit-test-currently-running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit of stretch, but you could implement a [RunListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) and add it to surefire. See how to configure it [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html).

Comment: Instead, why not log the test name from the test code itself ?

Comment: For anyone using JUnit 5, you can now provide a TestExecutionListener : https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-listeners

Answer (score 6):

In details

```
package com.example.mavenproject;

import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;

/**
 * @author Paul Verest
 */
public class PrintOutCurrentTestRunListener extends RunListener {
    @Override
    public void testRunStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        // TODO all methods return null
        System.out.println("testRunStarted " + description.getClassName() + " " + description.getDisplayName() + " "
                + description.toString());
    }

    public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("testStarted "
                + description.toString());
    }

    public void testFinished(Description description) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("testFinished "
                + description.toString());
    }

    public void testRunFinished(Result result) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("testRunFinished " + result.toString()
                + " time:"+result.getRunTime()
                +" R"+result.getRunCount()
                +" F"+result.getFailureCount()
                +" I"+result.getIgnoreCount()
                );
    }
}
```

and in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<!-- -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>com.example.mavenproject.PrintOutCurrentTestRunListener</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Does not appear as though `System.out.println` makes it into the Maven console log, nor any report.

Comment: It works for junit 4 only, in junit 5 you must use `TestExecutionListener` (see [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49938919/1276632))

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can run maven in debug mode with `--debug` or `-X` flags

Comment: It doesn't log successfully executed tests.