# JUnit 5: Is it possible to set a TestExecutionListener in Maven Surefire Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I want to use JUnit 5 and the `TestExecutionListener` interface to do some clean up after the test run is done. The whole project is using JUnit Jupiter, no Vintage involved.

In Maven Surefire it was able to set a JUnit 4 `RunListener` via configuration to archive this. Is Surefire able to recognize the new JUnit 5 `TestExecutionListener`? If not, is there any way to have JUnit 5 tests and use the `TestExecutionListener` or `RunListener`?

I do not want to create my own Launcher just to execute tests with the listener.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maven Surefire does currently not support adding a `TestExecutionListener` via its configuration. I think you should open an issue for them because they are currently incorporating the JUnit team's custom provider into their codebase.

However, you can register your custom `TestExecutionListener` via the Service Loader mechanism described in the [User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Somehow I missed this paragraph in the user guide. For everybody who is not familiar with the Service Loader mechanism, like me, try the Google AutoService library: https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service

Comment: There is not way to cleanly print something on screen, is there? From the `ServiceLoader`-loaded `TestExecutionListener` there is no access to the Maven logger.

Comment: Is there some static way to access the Maven logger?